# How can I type ASCII characters like Alt + numpad in Windows?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unicode-entry, ascii

On Windows, the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>+ <kbd>5</kbd>+ <kbd>5</kbd> creates a blank space. How can I achieve this on Ubuntu?

Comment: As this is a lot more cumbersome under Linux than on Windows: Is there a table?

Comment: @empedokles I always use http://unicode-table.com/, but the Character Map application also shows the unicode value of the selected character in the status bar.

Answer (score 70):

When you type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *numbers* in Windows, you are actually typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *character's [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code*.

To achieve the same in Ubuntu, you must type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, and then type *Unicode codepoint*.

If this shurtcut doesn't work [check if your input method is iBus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050341/349837).

#### Example 1

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `255` on Windows creates a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (ASCII 255)
- This character in Unicode is U+00A0
- On Ubuntu, type it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>, then <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just release all keys

#### Example 2

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `173` on Windows creates an inverted exclamation mark (ASCII 173, "¡")
- This character in Unicode is U+00A1
- On Ubuntu, type it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just release all keys.

The Unicode four-digit hexadecimal number can be found via the **Character Map** (`gucharmap`). For just ASCII table type `man ascii` on a terminal.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I also would like to know the unicode code for windows alt+173 in ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need to hold Ctrl-Shift for the whole number, you can release them after the "u", and add a space at end of code.

Comment: @Valladao, I updated my answer to better explain how to type these characters in general, and I included both 173 and 255 as examples.

Comment: @enzotib nice to know I can let go of those keys and actually type with my left hand. :)

Comment: it may be important to note, that this won't work if your caps are locked

Comment: ctrl+shift+u does not work on my laptop after 13.10. Why?

Comment: Alt + 010003 gives ✓ sign. And the same for any unicode symbol. Unicode does not mean hexadecimal.

Comment: It wasn't working for me on Ubuntu 14.04 so I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/854465/11929 to change keyboard input method from none to ibus under Language Support, logged out/in and it works now.

Comment: also to note, letters capitalized in the code can be entered as lowercase.

Comment: Recent downvoter, care to share a reason?

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker Just a guess for downvote: As others have said, this doesn't seem to work. I'm trying it in 14.04 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 19):

### Another way — «Compose key»

> A compose key, available on some computer keyboards, is a special kind
>   of modifier key designated to signal the software to interpret the
>   following (usually two) keystrokes as a combination in order to
>   produce a character not found directly on the keyboard. **For example**,
>   striking **Compose** followed by **O** and then **C** can produce the
>   symbol **©**, the copyright symbol). [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key)

- **ENABLE [Ubuntu 13.04]:** System settings... → Keyboard → Layout settings → Options → «Compose key position» and set it, for example, on «Menu» (key between right ALT and CTRL).
- **DO:** Hold key «Menu» and push «Space» 2 times. Should get 1 non-breaking space: « ».

Here more **Linux compose key sequences:** [hermit.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140215122421/http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html)

Comment: FWIW, in 14.04 the compose setting is under System settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> typing -> compose key

Comment: Compose key is neat! I now found a good replacement for the CapsLock key and am able to easily insert the various symbols that I used to struggle with earlier.

Comment: Sadly you can't bind compose cay anyway (Win key), but place it on Caps lock is maybe even better! I hate accidentally caps lock key pressing :)

Comment: See answer for Ubuntu 18.04 and later: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028964/493153