# Ctrl + shift + U combo does not work

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, unicode

When i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, nothing happens. The underlined U does not appear, so I cannot write unicode. I am running Xubuntu 14.04.

Thanks.

Comment: Google Docs, but in previous installation of Xubuntu all worked fine.

Comment: Try Ctrl + U. It works for me. :)

Comment: Same here, Shift+Ctrl+U does not work in 14.04, like it is said here: help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Unicode_composition

Comment: I have the same problem and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was simple - `Fedora 29` && `Gnome 3.30.1`

Just run: `ibus-setup` > `Emoji Tab` and change shortcuts for `unicode code point` and `Emoji annotation` to something different.

`ibus-setup` is shipped with package `ibus-1.5.19-4.fc29.src.rpm`

No need for restart nor logging out from current session.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome classic...

Fixed it by going to Applications -> System Tools -> Language and support.
On the Language tab, i switched "Keyboard input method" from "none" to "iBus".
Logout/login or restart computer, and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> Unicode input shortcut seems to be a feature of iBus. To use it, you have to enable iBus as an input method.

First, make sure iBus is installed on your system:

```
sudo apt install ibus
```

Then, go to your Language Support settings and choose "iBus" as the keyboard input method:

[image: Screenshot of the Language Support window with the "Keyboard input method system" menu activated]

Log out and log in again (or restart your system) for the changes to take effect.

If the shortcut is still not working, it could be that the shortcut is being overridden (used for something else) as Mohamed Ramzy Helmy [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/604356/20096) in a previous answer. In that case, you will have to go to your settings and disable the other keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04, the default hotkey <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
<kbd>U</kbd> can be disabled.

1. Open dconf-editor, go to the path: `/desktop/ibus/panel/emoji/Unicode-hotkey`.
2. Remove the default value by set custom value to `[]`.

   [image: snapshot of dconf-editor]

Answer (score -1):

The key combination didn’t work because some other program used it. To fix this I used gconf-editor.

Open gconf-editor.
Choose desktop -> ibus -> general -> hotkey.
Open trigger parameter.

Remove <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combination from the list and press OK.

Comment: I do not have ibus option in gconf-editor, there is only gnome option.

Comment: sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-clutter ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-qt4
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin # or other engine(s) you want

Comment: Please [edit] your answer, if you want to add relevant information like that in your previous comment.