# How to type peso sign in Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: text, unicode-entry

I'm still cannot figure out how to type a Philippine peso sign in LibreOffice and other application like Tomboy note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peso sign in Unicode is at: `(U+20B1)` so you can type it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, on pressing this an underlined `u` character will appear. Now press <kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and press enter, you'll then get:

₱

**Courtesy:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Unicode_composition
**An example:** https://askubuntu.com/a/12428/11932